# Unable to view content of CHM file in Windows help viewer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, chm

I have CHM file that always displays the same error:
"Navigation to the webpage was canceled"

All nodes have the same error.

[image: Screenshot]

What can I do to fix it?

I am running Windows XP SP3 w/Internet Explorer 8.0.6001

Comment: There is a way to specifically enable full access to HTML in the intranet intranet, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Is the .chm file on a network share?  Or was it downloaded from the internet or from a network share?  Windows protects files it deems "untrusted" and prevents them from being displayed.  To fix the issue, copy the chm to your local machine, then right click on the file and select "Properties" and click on the "Unblock" button.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the u[n]block button on my Properties dialog.

Answer (score 4):

Let me guess the CHM file was downloaded from the internet? This is a security mechanism. If you trust that file (and remember - CHM files contain HTML and scripts running under an external executable), just right-click it, select properties and then select "unblock".

Since this looks like a Mercury (should I say HP?) file, you're probably good - as long as you downloaded it from an authorized site.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have write access to the CHM file and the folder it resides in.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to know that you can 'extract' or decompile CHM files using the free archiving tool 7Zip. CHMs are a lot more fun to browse inside a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution when actually working over a (trusted) network share is to **transfer the CHM file within an archive** (zip, rar, etc.). After extracting it from the archive, the CHM will be shown without an observable restriction. The reason is that (after [KB896358](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896358/ms05-026-a-vulnerability-in-html-help-could-allow-remote-code-executio)) for downloaded files [special security restrictions apply](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/seanearp/2007/05/28/cant-read-chm-compiled-help-on-vistaxp2003/). You can disable these restrictions by introducing two keys into the registry as described in this (German) article: 
 [Problem beim Anzeigen von .chm-Dateien - Tipps & Tricks](https://www.wintotal.de/tipp/problem-beim-anzeigen-von-chm-dateien/)

Extracted patch to the registry (enabling intranet content):<sup>[1]</sup>

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\HHRestrictions]
"MaxAllowedZone"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\ItssRestrictions]
"MaxAllowedZone"=dword:00000001
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I tried the modifications step by step and found the `HHRestrictions` key irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a CHM viewer that doesn't have this problem. Both SumatraPDF (http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) and XCHM (http://xchm.sourceforge.net/) are free, open-source CHM readers that don't have the same problem with opening those files as built-in chm viewer in windows.